# Kafka not starting on windows

Tags: apache-kafka

I have installed Zookeeper and Kakfa separately. Have started Zookeeper successfully. When I try to start Kafka on windows using the command,

```sh
C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.0\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties
```

I keep getting,

```sh
\Novosoft\C2J\Bin\c2jruntime.zip was unexpected at this time.
```

Not sure what's causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My environment variables had the CLASSPATH variable set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Novosoft\C2J\Bin\c2jruntime.zip.

Maybe Kafka was not liking it. Removed it and worked.

Kafka server started now